# Performing a multi-valued update in postgres with dates

Tags: postgresql, date, types

I am performing a multi-valued update in postgres. However, the datatype `DATE` in postgres is giving me issues. I got the following code to perform the update, but it gives an error

```
update users as u set
  id = u2.id,
  appointment = u2.appointment
from (values
  (1, '2022-12-01'),
  (2, '2022-12-01')
) as u2(id, appointment)
where u2.id = u.id;
```

```
ERROR:  column "appointment" is of type date but expression is of type text
LINE 3:   appointment = u2.appointment
                        ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Normally postgres accepts dates in such a format, how should I perform this update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres first casts the date values as string when creating `u2`, meaning it cannot cast them as date again when performing the actual update. Cast the dates as date to solve the issue:

```
update users as u set
  id = u2.id,
  appointment = u2.appointment
from (values
  (1, CAST('2022-12-01' as date)),
  (2, CAST('2022-12-01' as date))
) as u2(id, appointment)
where u2.id = u.id;
```

SQLFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9f30e708c8508a2df94458b70399eb3a